# Using Yocto with a distribution using python3 by defaults

Tags: python, linux, yocto

More and more Linux distributions use python 3.x as default python, but [Yocto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto_Project) still uses python 2.7. How to use Yocto with one of those distributions?

Comment: What Linux distribution in your experience defaults to Python 3? I have only seen ones that use some applications based on Python3, but still default (as in start that version when typing `python` on the commandline) to python2.7

Comment: Archlinux (and Manjaro) uses python3 since at least a year.

Comment: How do you define `default`. Installed is not the same as default, do you get Python3 if you type python at the prompt?

Comment: `python` launchs python3 interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yocto always runs in a virtualenv. But I've found a way to trick it to use python 2 , setting the default python and including it in PATH env variable:

```
$ source oe-init-build-env build
$ mkdir build/python-bin
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python2 build/python-bin/python
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python2-config build/python-bin/python-config
$ export PATH=$(pwd)/build/python-bin:${PATH}
```

Thanks all for your help !

Comment: Yocto doesn't run in a virtualenv by default.

Comment: I'm not using Yocto anymore, so I'm not sure. But the [doc](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Using_virtualenv) states that "the recommend usage is to install these dependencies in a Python virtual environment using pip.".

Answer (score 1):

The canonical solution here is to use virtualenv to create an environment where "python" is python 2.

Comment: this doesn't work because bitbake requires python3.. 0o

Comment: But the question was specifically about releases where yocto uses py2.

Comment: the problem also stands for current yocto releases... bitbake needs python3 and some of the internal recipies from openembedded require python to be python2...
if you set an virtualenv for only python2, bitbake does not run...

I ran into the same problem and there is some hardcoding done inside of some of the oe recipes symlinking it to the hosttools...

Comment: It would have been great if you could expand on your answer and explain install and usage of virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by overwriting the hosttools symlink yocto creates..
I managed to start the yocto build with the fix from Shan-x but it didn't build through.

Yocto sources a different env for all recipes.. Some of the recipes, especially from meta-openembedded require *hosttools*. These hosttools are for example python (which is then expected to be python2).
This hosttools are then symlinked in *build/tmp/hosttools* and this gets added to $PATH.

> python -> /usr/bin/python

to change this to default to python2 just change the symlink to point to /usr/bin/python2

The entire setup:

```
$ mkdir build/python-bin
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python2 build/python-bin/python
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python2-config build/python-bin/python-config
$ mkdir -p build/tmp/hosttools
$ ln -sf /usr/bin/python2 build/tmp/hosttools/python
```

to automatically change to python2 add the export $PATH to
*sources/poky/oe-init-build-env* , just before the other stuff gets sourced:

```
diff --git a/oe-init-build-env b/oe-init-build-env
index e813230a98..c981358577 100755
--- a/oe-init-build-env
+++ b/oe-init-build-env
@@ -47,6 +47,8 @@ if [ -z "$OEROOT" ]; then
 fi
 unset THIS_SCRIPT

+export PATH=$(pwd)/build/python-bin:${PATH}
+
 export OEROOT
 . $OEROOT/scripts/oe-buildenv-internal &&
     TEMPLATECONF="$TEMPLATECONF" $OEROOT/scripts/oe-setup-builddir || {
```

and then source the env:

```
$ source oe-init-build-env build
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux distributions slowly transfer to Python3 on an application by application basis, by adapting the shebang line to use Python 3.

CentOS 7, Ubuntu 14.4 LTS, Debian Jessy all **default** to Python2.7 if you type `python` on the commandline.

If Yocto is installed using a package manager, it will be adapted to whatever works on the Linux distribution it works either with a generic sheband (loading `python`) or with an explicit one (loading `python2` or `python2.7`.

If you install Yocto yourself, and it might not work because the system you are on defaults to a python from the 3 series, you can adapt the shebang line from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

I assume that python2.7 will be available for a few years to come and installable on demands, even if python3 becomes the default on any of those distributions (just like python3 was available when not installed by default).

What you should consider when installing Yocto from source is run it in a [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/12.0.5) so that you setup a clean environment, that might be somewhat more work, depending on the dependencies, but ensures a clean working environment for your application, that cannot be broken by any system update of any packages. And if you do that your setup can even use a python2.7.X version different than that supplied by the Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I just completed a fresh qemux86-64 (default) build of kirstone on Ubuntu 22.04 by just creating a symlink to python2 and setting up PATH to point to that. For example, from the root of the yocto repo:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 ./python
export PATH=$PWD:$PATH
```

Crude but simple and effective.